# fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory for c++

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying some c++ code on CUDA. So first i have to include the header files.But i got error *fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory*. I have tried with g++ compilation on my terminal.
`g++ c4.cpp -o c3 -lcuda` and also tried `gcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 c4.cpp -lcudart -o has_cuda`. But both gives result. The header file is not in the location. Anybody knows how to get this file or resolve this issue.
(I faced the same import problem for `iostream` header. But that was due to .h file extension. But for this cuda header file, this logic is not working. For importing #include i have tried like this:
`g++ c3.cpp -o c3 -lpthread` . THis one worked for me.)
My code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cuda>
//#include <cuda_runtime.h>
//#include <stdlib>
#include <ctime>


int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

But how to get out of the cuda header problem. I got the same error for . Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include c4.cpp -o c3 -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 3):

the cuda header file is cuda.h. try

```
#include <cuda.h>
```

Your gcc command line should be

```
g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include c4.cpp -o c3 -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda
```

The `-I` comes before your cpp files. The `-L` comes before the `-l`

Comment: I have tried this first. It also gives the same error. _fatal error: cuda: No such file or directory._

For these two headers ' #include <iostream>
#include <thread> ' does not needs the .h extension. @Shloim

Comment: many header files in STL do not have an extension. The CUDA library header files do. This is not a compiler optimization to automatically add the missing ".h". The file itself has no extension.